# git merge commit removes files, but `git show SHA` doesn't show them being removed

Tags: git

I have this situation in git:

```
-F--M--F1-->
   /
  /
-D--D1-->
```

- F is a commit on a feature branch, which contains the file in question.
- D is a commit on the main development branch, which does not contain the file.
- M is a merge commit that merges the development branch into the feature branch.

If I checkout F, I see the file.
If I checkout M, the file is gone.

But `git show --name-status M` does NOT show the file being removed. It instead shows two other files with 'MM' (literally) in the status column, meaning both sides had changes in the merge.

What is happening? How is the file removed in commit M without git showing it as removed?

Comment: `git show` on a merge commit is very special. I think that only those files are shown that are different from both parents. In your case, the deleted file is identical to one of the parents (i.e., it is deleted in one parent, `D`, and deleted in the result `M`), so it is not shown.

Comment: Is there any way to show what happened in more detail?

Comment: `git show -m --name-status M` shows two diffs, one for each parent.

Comment: Thanks! Do you want to post all that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git show` on a merge commit is very special. Only those files are shown that are different from both parents. In your case, the deleted file is "identical" to one of the parents (i.e., it is deleted in one parent, `D`, and deleted in the result `M`), so it is not shown.

There is [a mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt--m) that can help:

```
git show -m M
```

This computes a diff to each parent and shows them as a separate patch (or whatever display mode you choose).

Comment: There are also `git show -c` and `git show --cc`; the default is `--cc`; neither is any good here and you want `-m`. (Just mentioning this for completeness.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably merged the main branch into the feature branch, not the other way around 
So the file is only visible to F

Comment: The direction in which a merge is made is not relevant; both directions produce the exact same result.

Comment: Yes, the main branch was merged into the feature branch.

Comment: so the direction is relevant, right? @joachim